# OutOfMemoryError error when changing the tint color of Vector images

Tags: java, android, out-of-memory, android-image

I have at least 48 small images that are displaying a vector images stored as an XML file in drawable. I have a multi choice listview with 48 items. When an item is checked I access to its image counterpart and change the tint of the image. if less than (approximately) 30 items is checked, there is no problem, but if it's more than that, an OutOfMemoryError is displayed. Here is example of the code:

```
   View.OnClickListener listener= new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               SparseBooleanArray checked = listView.getCheckedItemPositions();
               for (int i = 0; i < checked.size(); i++) {
                   // Item position in adapter
                   int position = checked.keyAt(i);
                   // Add sport if it is checked i.e.) == TRUE!
                   image = null;
                   if (checked.valueAt(i)) {
                       switch (position) {
                           case 1:
                               image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image1);
                               image.setColorFilter(R.color.green);
                               break;
                           case 2:
                               image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image2);
                               image.setColorFilter(R.color.green);
                               break;
                           case 3:
                               image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image3);
                               image.setColorFilter(R.color.green);
                               break;
                            ....
                            case:48
                               image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image48);
                               image.setColorFilter(R.color.green);
                               break;
                               }
                           }
                     }
 mybutton.OnClickListener(listener)
```

example of the images in xml file

```
<RelativeLayout>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="400dp"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            android:src="@drawable/img45"
            android:id="@+id/image1"
            />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="400dp"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            android:src="@drawable/img45"
            android:id="@+id/image2"
            />
....
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="400dp"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            android:src="@drawable/img45"
            android:id="@+id/image48"
            />
</RelativeLayout>
```

It seems that the problem is common with Bitmap images, but the solution proposed in the previous questions does not suit my case. Do you think if I change the src of the images from an xml vector to a simple png would fix the problem? if not, Any suggestion?

Comment: the code is there: image.setColorFilter(R.color.green);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a separate color filter for each image.  Creating a single color filter and using it on all images would reduce object usage.  But if the image view is immediately creating a new bitmap with the shading you're going to go OOM no matter what-  you're creating 48 new bitmaps here, which is a huge amount of memory.

Secondly, every time you check a single item, you're creating new filters for all images.  That's just horribly inefficient (especially since you have n time searches in each case) and would make the problems in the previous paragraph worse.  Only change the single item that was clicked in each click handler.  Doing it this war creates sum (i=1 to n) i new images where n is the number of images clicked-  for n=30 that's 430ish.

As an aside-  using a switch statement here is horrible.  Create an array of imageViews at start time and index into the array, rather than using findViewById each time which does an O(n) search through your view tree.  This code is pretty bad all around.

Comment: That's a perfect answer. I didn't realise I can do two things in Android, first, creating an array of imageViews, secondly (most importantly), calling a method called OnItemClickListener. Yes, after reading your answer I realised how bad my code is.